# ExpressionEvaluationFailed. The execution of template action 'For_each' failed:

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-sentinel

I get the following error when I test a flow I've created:

> ExpressionEvaluationFailed. The execution of template action 'For_each' failed: the result of the evaluation of 'foreach' expression '@triggerBody()?['incidentUpdates']' is of type 'Null'. The result must be a valid array.

[image]

[image]

Does anyone have any tips on what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks so much!

I am trying to implement A recurring playbook that triggers at knock-off hour every day (Mon-Friday), The paybook collects infomation about incident id , name , description  , url
All the incidends assigned to the analyst, projected on a HTML table and send it to one of my colleagues.

JSON output from the first action in the flow:

```
"headers": {

        "Connection": "Close",

        "Accept": "*/*",

        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate",

        "Accept-Language": "en",

        "Host": "management.southafricanorth.logic.azure.com",

        "Referer": "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/17eeca6a-0dea-41e9-8fc9-f12b59cfad62/resourcegroups/ACSA_CSOC_RG/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/All-incidents-in-a-given-time-frame/triggers/Microsoft_Sentinel_incident/run?api-version=2016-10-01",

        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0,(Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64),AppleWebKit/537.36,(KHTML, like Gecko),Chrome/113.0.0.0,Safari/537.36,Edg/113.0.1774.50",

        "x-ms-client-session-id": "6cfb9cdfea3248d3a41dba1f89e410ad",

        "x-ms-command-name": "Microsoft_Azure_EMA.",

        "x-ms-effective-locale": "en.en-us",

        "x-ms-client-request-id": "52e3f450-f914-46f0-9370-03e70fcda011",

        "sec-fetch-site": "same-site",

        "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",

        "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",

        "x-ms-arm-resource-system-data": "{\"lastModifiedBy\":\"lumka@phakamo.co.za\",\"lastModifiedByType\":\"User\",\"lastModifiedAt\":\"2023-05-26T11:12:11.5409557Z\"}",

        "x-ms-arm-request-tracking-id": "d4901af4-623e-4c2e-bd1a-78a0ea3be9d7",

        "x-ms-correlation-request-id": "d4901af4-623e-4c2e-bd1a-78a0ea3be9d7",

        "x-ms-routing-request-id": "SOUTHAFRICANORTH:20230526T111211Z:d4901af4-623e-4c2e-bd1a-78a0ea3be9d7",

        "x-ms-client-location": "southafricanorth",

        "x-ms-home-tenant-id": "fb62d46e-e86e-4673-ba82-b27b61d8202b",

        "x-ms-client-ip-address": "41.150.225.141",

        "x-ms-arm-service-request-id": "8ba39e8f-b89a-4d1c-ba60-0f23ebb8f715",

        "x-ms-management-group-ancestors": "fb62d46e-e86e-4673-ba82-b27b61d8202b",

        "x-ms-client-audience": "https://management.core.windows.net/",

        "x-ms-client-scope": "user_impersonation",

        "x-ms-client-acr": "1",

        "x-ms-client-app-id": "c44b4083-3bb0-49c1-b47d-974e53cbdf3c",

        "x-ms-client-app-id-acr": "2",

        "x-ms-client-tenant-id": "506a7cb6-60b5-4cc7-8dfc-28daca27e296",

        "x-ms-client-issuer": "https://sts.windows.net/506a7cb6-60b5-4cc7-8dfc-28daca27e296/",

        "x-ms-client-object-id": "807dd4d9-6007-4cac-a771-07cf40630ad8",

        "x-ms-client-puid": "100320012670DEE5",

        "x-ms-client-alt-sec-id": "",

        "x-ms-client-principal-id": "100320012670DEE5",

        "x-ms-client-authorization-source": "RoleBased",

        "x-ms-client-identity-provider": "",

        "x-ms-client-authentication-methods": "pwd, rsa, mfa",

        "x-ms-client-principal-group-membership-source": "Token",

        "x-ms-client-principal-name": "lumka@phakamo.co.za",

        "x-ms-client-family-name-encoded": "TGFuZ2E=",

        "x-ms-client-given-name-encoded": "THVta2E=",

        "x-ms-arm-network-source": "PublicNetwork",

        "traceparent": "00-b75aaa8c8d8f63a0ea3110c0d52770a4-cae5b018000a229b-01",

        "x-ms-activity-vector": "IN.09",

        "Content-Length": "0",

        "Content-Type": "application/json"

    }

}
```

Comment: Whatever IncidentUpdates is, it’s not an array, it’s null. Can you provide (mask/scramble any data) the body of your trigger? It’ll help us help you.

Comment: @Skin Please see picture above

Comment: No, sorry, the trigger body comes out of the trigger. It’s JSON, it’ll be in the output of a successful run.

Comment: @Skin I just added an image showing the results after running the playbook, however, I do not see any JSON output.Kindly advice

Comment: Your trigger is the first action in the flow, what does the output of that look like on a successful run?

Comment: @Skin Kindly see the JSON output from the first action in the flow

Comment: @Skin kindly advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reproducing from my end, I received the same error as yours when I tried to iterate a value in `For_each` loop which is null and not array.

[image]

[image]

If you are unaware of the values that you are receiving in the required value that needs to be iterated, then I would recommend you to use `Compose` action to view the values that are received in the required value as below.

[image]

[image]

You can check the values after each run from the run history from overview pane of your logic app.

[image]